# Is it appropriate in a sort of business related mail using "'em", contracted form of "them"?

Tags: word-usage

I was writing an email today, and I was supposed to write a phrase like this "did it for all of  'em", even though I eventually  changed it to them as them as that looked a little informal to me, I am not rally sure if this is what the case is?

and just for information, mail was not for any boss/manager, it was just for a colleague but she is in US and I am not so I didn't know whether it is okay or not?

Comment: It sounds quite informal, so I wouldn't use *'em* unless your e-mails from her were equally informal.

Comment: Too informal for business.

Comment: Off topic: writing advice/critique.

Comment: if your correspondent knows that you are a non-English speaker they'll let it slide, because they'll assume you are trying to try out some colloquialisms.

Comment: In Business emails.. it depends on the individual who observes this usage. Most may let it go....but some may not approve. I would suggest not using "them" at all times...

Answer (score 1):

The only place the contraction 'em has a use in writing is in fiction, where the goal is to portray a character's way of speaking. (Example: "The crowd cheered, 'Hit 'em again, harder!'") It's never used in written communication, no matter how informal.

Comment: I’ve seen it in email — which is presumably a written not an oral medium.  It’s just that it is sometimes seeking to emulate one.

Comment: gmcgath -That was a fine way of putting it... " 'em"  is a big no-no in written communication. maybe ok while texting. anything is accepted in that lingo nowadays.. :)